# Django accessing the current key inside Foreign key in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my Django admin app I have:

```
class Bags(models.Model):
    bid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    b_name = models.TextField()

class Chits(models.Model):
    cid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    c_bid = models.ForeignKey(Bags, db_column='c_bid')

    def getb_name(self):
        return Bags <How do i get the Bags object here ?>
```

In my Admin, Chits is cascaded into Bags. So foreach entry in Bags I have some chits. How do i get the Bags.b_name inside each Chits ?

New to Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.c_bid` gives you the `Bags` object related to the `Chits` instance.

Therefore, you can do it like this:

```
def getb_name(self):
    # I guess you want to return the related b_name from your method name
    return self.c_bid.b_name
```

Moreover, if you want to get `Bags` objects in your view, you can do:

```
Bags.objects.filter(some_conditions)  # get QuerySets
```

or

```
Bags.objects.get(bid=some_integers)  # retrieving a single `Bags` object
```

Some documentations you can refer to: [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#making-queries), [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get), [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets)

Comment: Perfect. I missed c_bid in self.c_bid.b_name.